# how to submit to perforce a non-English file?

Tags: file, submit, perforce

It is possible to submit a non-English file to perforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Perforce can store any kind of file regardless of human language, programming language, or binary format.

If you want to submit Unicode files and have them translated into different character sets on different platforms (rather than just treating them as binary blobs), and/or you want to be able to have Unicode characters in file names, see https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/superuser.unicode.html.